# Laravel Slow Response of an Ajax request to a controller method returning JSON Data

Tags: json, ajax, laravel, performance

I am trying to perform an Ajax request from view to a controller which returns JSON Data. Everything is working fine however the Ajax response is too slow.

This is my Ajax Request in view:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#search', function () {
    $("#phoneBody > tr").remove();
    var query = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var expression = new RegExp(query, "i");
    $.getJSON("phonetest/" + query, function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            if (value.name.search(expression) != -1 ||
                value.extn.search(expression) != -1 ||
                value.mobile.search(expression) != -1 ||
                value.dept.search(expression) != -1 ||
                value.desig.search(expression) != -1 ||
                value.emp_cd.search(expression) != -1)
            {
                $('#phoneBody').append('<tr><td class="name">' + value.name +
                                       '</td><td class="extn">' + value.extn + '</td><td>' +
                                       value.email + '</td><td>' + value.voip + '</td><td>' +
                                       value.mobile + '</td><td>' + value.floor + '</td><td>' +
                                       value.dept + '</td><td>' + value.desig + '</td></tr>');
            }
        });
    });

});
```

This is my controller method:

```
public function phonetest(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->ajax()) {
        $crawler = Goutte::request('GET', "http://1.1.1.1/test.NSF/names?OpenView&count=2000");

        $emp_arr = $crawler->filter('tr')->each(function ($node) {
            $rec['name']   = $node->filter('a')->eq(0)->text();
            $rec['extn']   = $node->filter('td')->eq(1)->text();
            $rec['voip']   = $node->filter('td')->eq(2)->text();
            $rec['mobile'] = $node->filter('td')->eq(3)->text();
            $rec['floor']  = $node->filter('td')->eq(4)->text();
            $rec['dept']   = $node->filter('td')->eq(5)->text();
            $rec['desig']  = $node->filter('td')->eq(6)->text();
            $rec['emp_cd'] = $node->filter('td')->eq(7)->text();

            $email        = DB::table('employee1')
                ->where('emp1_code', $rec['emp_cd'])
                ->pluck('emp1_email_addr')
                ->first();
            $rec['email'] = strtolower($email);
            //dd($rec);

            return $rec;
        });
        $emp_arr = array_values(array_filter($emp_arr));

        return json_encode($emp_arr);
    }
}
```

Everything works fine. However, the response is too slow. It takes literally 1 second for each character I type. How can I improve the same?

One approach would be to create the initial array while the view loads for the first time and then make Ajax requests to the array subsequently.

**Solved**

I put the JSON in session while page load. Subsequent Ajax requests are served from this JSON stored in Session. This is working as of now and Ajax responses are superfast. Will monitor the performance over time in case JSON becomes big in size.

Comment: The easier you make it for ppl to help you, the more likely you are to get help.  Just dumping a bunch of code here without explaining what you're doing doesn't make it easy.  It looks like you're doing some kind of autocomplete, your JS first makes an AJAX request to your controller, which itself then makes *another* http request to another service?  Chaining 2 http requests is going to be your bottleneck.  No matter what else you do, that's always going to be slow.  Any chance to re-architect things so you can avoid that?

Comment: Its basically this - I have a legacy lotus notes application serving as a static telephone number directory of employees. Now there's a new application coming up which requires Live search of employee information including telephone numbers. Now What I am trying to do is web scraping the lotus notes application page using PHP Goutte Web scraper and getting the results in JSON. Then generating an AJAX request with keyup function on the input field and returning results from this JSON.

Comment: I'd suggest editing your question and adding that info.  What about scraping all the data from the Notes site and saving it to your new DB, so you don't need to do that "live"?

Comment: I thought of this approach. However, the notes page keeps getting updated, although not frequently. So is it a good idea to repopulate the DB table on every page load?